# Integrating Jenkins / Puppet / Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, puppet

I have a multi-module project in maven that builds several artifacts (some wars), I am using puppet for configuration management and also for deployment via ensure latest package is installed from my local internal deb repo

I'm using Jenkins for CI and would like to use it to deploy to the repo in case of a successful build.

Here is the problem, I want to package the artifacts as deb with semantic version so each time there is a new version of the artifact I have a new deb package I can put in my local repo and than run puppet to deploy changes on all machines.

But I want only the changed artifacts to be updated, not update all sub module deb packages on each commit, how do I do that ?

Comment: Does each artifact have its own build job (which presumably builds the deb and deploys it to your artifact repository)? If it does, what is causing all artifacts to be updated? Are you not using snapshot builds?

Comment: No, the build is through the parent project. So it manages dependencies etc.

Comment: You'll need one deploy job per deployable artifact. Sorry don't have time right now to provide a full answer, but the basic gist is: your main build kicks off many deploy jobs on success, and each deploy job checks for change in version. If no change, then no deploy.

Comment: OK, that gives me a direction thx ! my question is how do the deploy job knows there was no change ?

Comment: Any way you can get it to work. MD5 checksums are good. If you check in a version file every time you want a non-snapshot release, then you can use the git SHA1 of that file. Last change date of the latest commit? That might work. Personally, I prefer to deploy everything, every time: that reduces the chance that a build-environment (as opposed to code) change has caused problems.